# usar i18n or la función de date-fns directamente

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Estoy cambiando moment por date-fns y tengo la siguiente función que tengo que sustituir.

```
    start: moment().startOf('year').locale(this.$i18n.locale).toDate(),
    end: moment().endOf('year').locale(this.$i18n.locale).toDate(),
```

mi primera idea fue la siguiente, para continuar utilizando **this.$i18n.locale**

```
    start: localYearStart(this.$i18n.locale),
    end: localYearEnd(this.$i18n.locale),
```

```
export const localYearStart = (localDate) => {
    const localTimeZone = getLocalTimeZone(localDate);
    const formattedLocalDate = format(new Date(), 'PPpp', {locale:localTimeZone, weekStartsOn:monday});

    return startOfYear(new Date(formattedLocalDate))
}
```

Pero si utilizo la siguiente función, obtengo el mismo resultado

```
export const firstDayOfCurrentYear = () => {
    return startOfYear(NEW_DATE);
}
```

Mi duda es, si debería utilizar la primera función o la segunda. Es mi primer trabajo como front junior y mi primer mes y medio además esta es mi primera tarea y no quiero hacerlo mal.

Comment: Una forma de resolver este tipo de dudas por tu cuenta es hacer pruebas unitarias de los métodos. Cubrir varios escenarios sabiendo lo que debería retornar o no la función.

Comment: Es lo que me gustaría, pero el proyecto no tiene test y lo que he hecho es crear un entorno de vue para ir probando el resultado, ya que el proyecto está en vue. 

Primero empece con node y no estaba mal, sólo que tenía el inconveniente de pintar el resultado diferente, así que probé con jasmine en el browser, pero fue imposible hacer que funcionara, y la última opción ha sido lo de vue. 

Acabo de aterrizar en el proyecto y este cambio es gordo y meter test ya sería un poco locura.